# How to search sequence of API call using IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly, malware, static-analysis

I want to search the sequence of API call using IDA Pro. How to search the API call node execution and what is the next API call node execution followed using IDA Pro.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, other than searching for the first call and then browsing the results to check for the second call. Or write a a script to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at https://github.com/deresz/funcap. It might not have all the sequencing information you're looking for but I used it as a basis to do something similar a while ago.

If you don't want to do it dynamically with IDA's debugger, you can similarly use an IDA Python script to parse the callgraph of a binary. I think Grey Hat Python has a section on IDA Python if you don't want to/can't find open source resources (though I believe there are other plugins that do something like this).